# Slide to specific part of image in Android

Tags: java, android, image, imageview, android-photoview

I'm trying to build some kind of smart map. To do that I need to display specific part of picture (in this case floor plan). So we will have quite big picture (let's assume 3000x3000px) with some rooms (with irregular sizes and shapes) and if location changed we need to should smooth slide to this specific position. As I said before rooms will be with irregular sizes so also there should be an option to zoom out and zoom (programaticlly) in at specific position.

Use case how it should work.

1. App location changed
2. `ImageView` instead of displaying whole picture of floor plan smooth slide to specific coords and zoom this part of picture

Is this possible to do that on `ImageView` or something like `PhotoView` ?

[image]